What is the Haar measure in the SU(2) group?
I have seen that in the literature, specifically Greiner's book on Quantum Mechanical Symmetries, he talks about the Haar measure and gives an example for the case of SU(2), where the result is
8$\pi$, but in other books they mention that the result is 2$\pi^{2}$. Why is it that the Haar measure has these two different results in the literature?

Because Haar measure is defined up to a multiplicative constant.

If $\mu$ is a Haar measure on a compact Lie group $G$, so is $k\mu$ for any positive constant $k$. The Haar property is about comparing the measures of subsets related to each other by group action. It is not about the measure of the whole group. Sometimes it is convenient to normalize the measure of the entire group to be equal to $1$.
